# Keep getting invalid expired token in tweepy twitter app

Tags: python, twitter

I'm working on a basic twitter app, using the Tweepy python library, to unfollow people who don't follow me. Yesterday I had it running and it was working fine. Today it keeps failing: as soon as I connect, I get an error message: Invalid or Expired Token, code 89.
If I go to my Twitter app page in dev.twitter.com, the app is there and hasn't been suspended, but on the Keys and Access Tokens tab, it doesn't have any access token and says I need to create one. If I create one, and run the program again, the same thing happens.
the source code is below. I've tried googling and searching here and can't find a solution. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
import tweepy, time, sys
CONSUMER_KEY = "..."
CONSUMER_SECRET = "..."
ACCESS_KEY = "...-..."
ACCESS_SECRET = "..."
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

followers = api.followers_ids('@...')
friends = api.friends_ids('@...')

for f in friends:
    if f not in followers:
        print "Unfollow {0}?".format(api.get_user(f).screen_name)
        if raw_input("Y/N?") == 'y' or 'Y':
            api.destroy_friendship(f)
```

Comment: Try reading this thread https://twittercommunity.com/t/solved-errors-message-invalid-or-expired-token-code-89/10797/9

Comment: Could you try deleting the app in it's entirety and setting a new one up? Also, chances are you've exceeded your API limit

Comment: It can't be API Limit. Tweepy will throw a different explicit exception for that (RateLimitError), if their doco is to be believed.. This isn't one of those (it's a TweepError). Also I tried deleting it and creating a new app. It worked a charm.. for a while. I set it on a loop to destroy friendships every 10 seconds. Went for about 10 minutes then suddenyl stopped with the invalid or expired token error. And now throws that again.

Comment: Too many requests per minute?

Comment: OK seemed like it was too many requests. I changed it to a time.sleep running every 10 seconds and it was happening. Then I changed the time.sleep to every 60 seconds and Twitter seemed happy. That is weird because the tweepy doco says it logs RateLimitError separately to TweepyError. So I think tweepy needs to handle an Invalid Expired Token code 89 as a RateLimitError, to make it clearer. Not sure how activce it is on github...